# nextauthjs nextjs : Problem with trying to set up onboarding page. User is able to skip the onboarding

Tags: next.js, next-auth

So i have setup nextauth.js and redirection to an onboarding page if its the first time the user has signed up with google.

Below is my [...nextauth]/route.js

```
export const authOptions = {

    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),

    providers: [
        // Google Provider
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
        })

    ],
    
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
        newUser: '/onBoarding'
      }



}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

As you can see , I have added a newUser under pages - this allows me to redirect to onBoarding whenever its the first time a user signs in.

My middleware.ts is below,

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
//middleware for nextauth.js
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!|api|login).*)", "/", "/onBoarding"],
};
```

This ensures the user is authenticated to view the onboarding and home page.

However, the main problem I am facing is ensuring the user cannot enter the "/" path without finishing the onBoarding process where the user sets the username. Basically once the onBoarding page is shown the user is able to move to the "/" or "/dashboard" or any other route without finishing the onBoarding.

One way is to check if the onBoarding flag is true before rendering every page but wont that be an unclean way to do it?

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: You can create a middleware that fetches the user, checks if he has completed the onboarding. If he didn't, you prevent it from going to other routes by redirecting to `/onBoarding`.

Comment: got it but how do I do that? I need to be able to search in my database mongoDB for which i need the session.  import { getServerSession } from "next-auth"; in middleware.ts gives me an error .  is it possible for you to give me an example?